# Como faço para usar Localização por GPS em minha aplicação WEB?

Tags: php, html, gps

estou criando uma aplicação e encontrei uma barreira, esta aplicação é para restaurantes monitorarem as entregas e da mesma forma o usuário, também faze-lo, eu estava fazendo por meio de checkUp's sempre que ele para-se, como nos correios, só que percebi que o entregador teria que parar para fazer o checkUp de cada entrega para poder atualizar o site na parte onde ficaria o status do serviço, e fora que o monitoramento poderia entrar em conflito por 'erros de usuário'.
Desculpem pela longa introdução, mas queria explanar o meu problema de forma que vocês entendessem o que eu procuro, bem, sendo assim, preciso saber se há como eu buscar a localização de um individuo(entregador), se possível, também definir rota e como eu o faria.
Desde já muito obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer isso com JS, seria algo mais ou menos assim: http://codepen.io/FuckingLunatic/pen/LNQqjm (veja funcionando aqui)

```
var x = document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else { 
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}

function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;  
}
```

Ai com isso você pode pensar na forma de ficar atualizando sempre o posicionamento do entregador